# Why do I get a different answer from Mathematica when calculating this integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am curious and confused about the solution of this integral.
$$\int_{t}^{T}(1-e^{\alpha(s-T)})e^{\alpha(t-s)}ds$$

When I use *Mathematica* with this code

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Integrate[(1 - Exp[α (s - T)])*Exp[α (t - s)], {s, t, 
  T}, Assumptions -> 0 <= t <= T, Assumptions -> α > 0]
```

the output is

```
(1 + E^((t - T) α) (-1 + t α - T α))/α
```

but apparently the solution to [the integral should be](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4473047/is-there-a-closed-form-expression-for-this-recursive-function/4473053?noredirect=1#comment9376126_4473053)
$$\frac{1}{\alpha}(1-e^{\alpha(t-T)})^2$$
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mathematica's result is correct.

Comment: Thank you but I don't understand the difference with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4473047/is-there-a-closed-form-expression-for-this-recursive-function/4473053?noredirect=1#comment9376126_4473053) question. Could you please help?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the answer to the linked question on Math.SE is the solution for the recursion relation $f_n(t)=\int_{t}^{T}f_{n-1}(\color{red}{t})e^{\alpha(t-s)}ds$, not $f_n(t)=\int_{t}^{T}f_{n-1}(\color{red}{s})e^{\alpha(t-s)}ds$ as requested.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Oh now I see where the mismatch is coming from. Thank you very much for pointing this out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check the Mma result (which is not absolutely straightforwardly here) let us first get the indefinite integral:

```
Integrate[(1 - Exp[α (s - T)])*Exp[α (t - s)], s, 
  Assumptions -> {α > 0, 0 <= t <= T, T > 0, t > 0}] // 
 Simplify[#, {α > 0, 0 <= t <= T, T > 0, t > 0}] &

(*  -((E^((-s + t) α) + E^((t - T) α) s α)/α)   *)
```

To better visualize it I show also the image:

[image]

Let us make sure that it is right:

```
D[-((E^((-s + t) α) + 
    E^((t - T) α) s α)/α), s] // 
 Simplify[#, {α > 0, 0 <= t <= T, T > 0, t > 0}] &

(*  E^((-s + t) α) - E^((t - T) α)  *)
```

[image]

which is equal to your original function:

```
(1 - Exp[α (s - T)])*Exp[α (t - s)] // 
 Simplify[#, {α > 0, 0 <= t <= T, T > 0, t > 0}] &

(*  E^((-s + t) α) - E^((t - T) α)  *)
```

Now, let us apply the Newton-Leibnitz theorem directly:

```
(-((E^((-s + t) α) + 
      E^((t - T) α) s α)/α) /. 
    s -> T) - (-((
     E^((-s + t) α) + 
      E^((t - T) α) s α)/α) /. s -> t) // 
 Simplify[#, {α > 0, 0 <= t <= T, T > 0, t > 0}] &

(* (1 + E^((t - T) α) (-1 + t α - T α))/α  *)
```

[image]

You can make sure that the result is equal to that obtained by Mma for the definite integral

```
Integrate[(1 - Exp[α (s - T)])*Exp[α (t - s)], {s, t, 
   T}, Assumptions -> {α > 0, 0 <= t <= T, T > 0, t > 0}] // 
 Simplify[#, {α > 0, 0 <= t <= T, T > 0, t > 0}] &

(*  (1 + E^((t - T) α) (-1 + t α - T α))/α  *)
```

Thus, as @Nasser wrote in his comment, Mma gives the right result.

Have fun!

Comment: By the Newton-Leibniz theorem do you mean the Barrow Theorem?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I mean this: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%9D%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0

Answer (score 3):

*Rewrite: Initial post had a blunder.*

This appears to be the answer:

```
f[n_] := α^(1-n) - (α^(1-n) Gamma[n, (T-t) α]) / Gamma[n];
```

It agrees with the first sixteen terms:

```
assum = (0 <= t <= s <= T) && α > 0 && n > 0 && 
   n ∈ Integers;
foo = NestList[
    Integrate[(# /. t -> s)*Exp[α (t - s)], {s, t, T}, 
      Assumptions -> assum] &,
    (1 - Exp[α (t - T)]),
    15]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {127.602, Null}  *)

foo - Table[f[n], {n, Length@foo}] // FunctionExpand // 
 FullSimplify[#, assum] &
(*  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}  *)
```

Proof left as an exercise.